# Sprint boot SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: 08003

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm getting the error below when I start my Java/Spring web application.  I used `SqlDeveloper` to connect to the Oracle DB and that seems to be working fine. What do you think could be the problem?

> 2018-05-28T16:26:03,863 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version 30 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.4.Final
>
> 2018-05-28T16:26:04,843 [RMI TCP
>   Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator 66- HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: CustomKitCart (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
>
> 2018-05-28T16:26:05,353 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]
>   INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator 69 - HHH000229:
>   Running schema validator
>
> 2018-05-28T16:29:08,070 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 127 - SQL Error:17008, SQLState: 08003
>
> 2018-05-28T16:29:08,070 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 129 - 关闭的连接: next
>
> 2018-05-28T16:29:08,084 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] WARN 
>    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext 544 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

Comment: It seems your Class CustomKitCart does not have a default constructor. Check the  stacktrace.

Comment: Add a default no-argument constructor for that class and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @IndraneelBende I added the default constructor. It didn't work.

Comment: Have u looked up what the error code above means?

Comment: @Sean have you found solution?